# Mongodb Count on multiple sub arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Calculate All the number of agreements, contacts and the group by it on company name. Note. Agreements and Contacts are array of objects

This is a sample document of my data:

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57c7bd8f51666ac615bc837d"),
    "ITBCompanyId" : 2296,
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-09-01T05:38:02.843Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-09-01T05:33:03.604Z"),
    "identifier" : "SOU10",
    "name" : "Source One Rehabilitation",
    "addressLine2" : null,
    "city" : "Plano",
    "state" : "TX",
    "zip" : "75024",
    "faxNumber" : "",
    "territoryId" : "11",
    "marketId" : null,
    "accountNumber" : "Source One Rehabilitation",
    "dateAcquired" : ISODate("2014-09-15T04:00:00.000Z"),
    "parentCompany" : null,
    "annualRevenue" : null,
    "numberOfEmployees" : null,
    "ownershipType" : null,
    "deletedBy" : null,
    "orgId" : "1",
    "deletedAt" : null,
    "_info" : {
        "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2016-09-01T05:12:32.000Z"),
        "updatedBy" : "LabTechInt"
    },
    "whois" : [],
    "configuration" : [],
    "contact" : [ 
        {
            "mobileGuid" : "6435d4c0-12fa-41d1-9db0-e4f9b1b4e7b2",
            "presence" : null,
            "gender" : null,
            "title" : null,
            "country" : null,
            "zip" : "75024",
            "state" : "TX",
            "city" : "Plano",
            "addressLine2" : null,
            "lastName" : null,
            "firstName" : "Dee Williams",
            "id" : 821,
            "_id" : ObjectId("57c7beba51666ac615bc8576"),
            "communicationItems" : [],
            "customFields" : null,
            "relationship" : {
                "name" : null,
                "id" : 0
            }
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 829,
            "firstName" : "Jesy",
            "lastName" : "Leon",
            "addressLine2" : null,
            "city" : "Plano",
            "state" : "TX",
            "zip" : "75024",
            "country" : null,
            "title" : null,
            "gender" : null,
            "presence" : null,
            "mobileGuid" : "2b0754c1-c256-4063-9cea-c40f9ca77084",

            "_id" : ObjectId("57c7beba51666ac615bc857d"),
            "communicationItems" : [ 
                {
                    "communicationType" : "Email",
                    "defaultFlag" : true,
                    "extension" : null,
                    "type" : {
                        "_info" : null,
                        "name" : "Email",
                        "id" : 1
                    },
                    "id" : 45587
                }, 
                {
                    "communicationType" : "Phone",
                    "defaultFlag" : true,
                    "extension" : null,
                    "value" : "9728012190",
                    "type" : {
                        "_info" : null,
                        "name" : "Direct",
                        "id" : 2
                    },
                    "id" : 45590
                }
            ],
            "customFields" : null,
            "company" : {
                "id" : "19390",
                "name" : "Source One Rehabilitation",
            },
            "relationship" : {
                "id" : 0,
                "name" : null
            }
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 850,
            "firstName" : "Dr.",
            "lastName" : "Gabriel",
            "addressLine2" : null,
            "city" : "Plano",
            "state" : "TX",
            "zip" : "75024",
            "country" : null,
            "title" : null,
            "gender" : null,
            "presence" : null,
            "mobileGuid" : "8c833a31-369d-4499-87cb-b5598826e653",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57c7beba51666ac615bc8592"),
            "communicationItems" : [ 
                {
                    "communicationType" : "Email",
                    "defaultFlag" : true,
                    "extension" : null,
                    "type" : {
                        "_info" : null,
                        "name" : "Email",
                        "id" : 1
                    },
                    "id" : 45627
                }, 
                {
                    "communicationType" : "Phone",
                    "defaultFlag" : true,
                    "extension" : null,
                    "value" : "9728012190",
                    "type" : {
                        "_info" : null,
                        "name" : "Direct",
                        "id" : 2
                    },
                    "id" : 45628
                }
            ],
            "customFields" : null,
            "relationship" : {
                "id" : 0,
                "name" : null
            }
        }
    ],
    "agreement" : [ 
        {
            "periodType" : null,
            "billAmount" : "0",
            "billTermsId" : 12,
            "billOneTimeFlag" : false,
            "billCycleId" : "2",
            "expiredDays" : "0",
            "coverAgreementExpense" : false,
            "coverAgreementProduct" : false,
            "coverAgreementTime" : true,
            "oneTimeFlag" : false,
            "applicationUnlimitedFlag" : true,
            "applicationCycle" : "CalendarMonth",
            "applicationLimit" : "0",
            "applicationUnits" : "Hours",
            "internalNotes" : "",
            "workOrder" : "",
            "slaId" : "2",
            "reasonCancelled" : "",
            "dateCancelled" : null,
            "cancelledFlag" : false,
            "noEndingDateFlag" : false,
            "endDate" : "2016-01-31T05:00:00Z",
            "startDate" : "2015-02-01T05:00:00Z",
            "businessUnitId" : 2,
            "locationId" : "11",
            "customerPO" : "",
            "parentAgreementId" : null,
            "name" : "Complete Managed Services Agreement",
            "id" : "109",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57c7bd9051666ac615bc83e3"),
            "_info" : {
                "updatedBy" : "Ali            ",
                "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2016-05-12T20:55:21.000Z")
            },
            "workType" : {
                "_info" : null,
                "name" : "Remote",
                "id" : "3"
            },
            "workRole" : {
                "_info" : null,
                "name" : "Support Engineer",
                "id" : "5"
            },
            "contact" : {
                "name" : "Heather B",
                "id" : "539"
            },
            "agreementType" : {
                "name" : "Complete Managed Services",
                "id" : "19"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "121",
            "name" : "Complete Managed Services: IMV",
            "parentAgreementId" : null,
            "customerPO" : "",
            "locationId" : "11",
            "businessUnitId" : 2,
            "startDate" : "2016-03-01T05:00:00Z",
            "endDate" : null,
            "noEndingDateFlag" : true,
            "cancelledFlag" : false,
            "dateCancelled" : null,
            "reasonCancelled" : "",
            "slaId" : "2",
            "workOrder" : "",
            "internalNotes" : "",
            "applicationUnits" : "Hours",
            "applicationLimit" : "0",
            "applicationCycle" : "CalendarMonth",
            "applicationUnlimitedFlag" : true,
            "oneTimeFlag" : false,
            "coverAgreementTime" : true,
            "coverAgreementProduct" : false,
            "coverAgreementExpense" : false,
            "expiredDays" : "0",
            "billCycleId" : "2",
            "billOneTimeFlag" : false,
            "billTermsId" : 12,
            "billAmount" : "0",
            "periodType" : null,
            "_id" : ObjectId("57c7bd9051666ac615bc83fa"),
            "_info" : {
                "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2016-05-12T22:11:59.000Z"),
                "updatedBy" : "Ali            "
            },
            "workType" : {
                "id" : "3",
                "name" : "Remote",
                "_info" : null
            },
            "workRole" : {
                "id" : "5",
                "name" : "Support Engineer",
                "_info" : null
            },
            "contact" : {
                "id" : "810",
                "name" : "Jarrod Rogers"
            },
            "agreementType" : {
                "id" : "19",
                "name" : "Complete Managed Services"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "122",
            "name" : "Complete Managed Servicess: FTW",
            "parentAgreementId" : null,
            "customerPO" : "",
            "locationId" : "11",
            "businessUnitId" : 2,
            "startDate" : "2016-03-01T05:00:00Z",
            "endDate" : null,
            "noEndingDateFlag" : true,
            "cancelledFlag" : false,
            "dateCancelled" : null,
            "reasonCancelled" : "",
            "slaId" : "2",
            "workOrder" : "",
            "internalNotes" : "",
            "applicationUnits" : "Hours",
            "applicationLimit" : "0",
            "applicationCycle" : "CalendarMonth",
            "applicationUnlimitedFlag" : true,
            "oneTimeFlag" : false,
            "coverAgreementTime" : true,
            "coverAgreementProduct" : false,
            "coverAgreementExpense" : false,
            "expiredDays" : "0",
            "billCycleId" : "2",
            "billOneTimeFlag" : false,
            "billTermsId" : 12,
            "billAmount" : "0",
            "periodType" : null,
            "_id" : ObjectId("57c7bd9051666ac615bc83fd"),
            "_info" : {
                "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2016-05-12T22:14:29.000Z"),
                "updatedBy" : "Ali            "
            },
            "workType" : {
                "id" : "3",
                "name" : "Remote",
                "_info" : null
            },
            "workRole" : {
                "id" : "5",
                "name" : "Support Engineer",
                "_info" : null
            },
            "contact" : {
                "id" : "810",
                "name" : "Jarrod Rogers"
            },
            "agreementType" : {
                "id" : "19",
                "name" : "Complete Managed Services"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "123",
            "name" : "Complete Managed Servicess: SC",
            "parentAgreementId" : null,
            "customerPO" : "",
            "locationId" : "11",
            "businessUnitId" : 2,
            "startDate" : "2016-03-01T05:00:00Z",
            "endDate" : null,
            "noEndingDateFlag" : true,
            "cancelledFlag" : false,
            "dateCancelled" : null,
            "reasonCancelled" : "",
            "slaId" : "2",
            "workOrder" : "",
            "internalNotes" : "",
            "applicationUnits" : "Hours",
            "applicationLimit" : "0",
            "applicationCycle" : "CalendarMonth",
            "applicationUnlimitedFlag" : true,
            "oneTimeFlag" : false,
            "coverAgreementTime" : true,
            "coverAgreementProduct" : false,
            "coverAgreementExpense" : false,
            "expiredDays" : "0",
            "billCycleId" : "2",
            "billOneTimeFlag" : false,
            "billTermsId" : 12,
            "billAmount" : "0",
            "periodType" : null,
            "_id" : ObjectId("57c7bd9051666ac615bc83ff"),
            "_info" : {
                "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2016-05-12T22:13:59.000Z"),
                "updatedBy" : "Ali            "
            },
            "workType" : {
                "id" : "3",
                "name" : "Remote",
                "_info" : null
            },
            "workRole" : {
                "id" : "5",
                "name" : "Support Engineer",
                "_info" : null
            },
            "contact" : {
                "id" : "810",
                "name" : "Jarrod Rogers"
            },
            "agreementType" : {
                "id" : "19",
                "name" : "Complete Managed Services"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "124",
            "name" : "Complete Managed Servicess: Psych",
            "parentAgreementId" : null,
            "customerPO" : "",
            "locationId" : "11",
            "businessUnitId" : 2,
            "startDate" : "2016-03-01T05:00:00Z",
            "endDate" : "2016-05-31T04:00:00Z",
            "noEndingDateFlag" : false,
            "cancelledFlag" : false,
            "dateCancelled" : null,
            "reasonCancelled" : "",
            "slaId" : "2",
            "workOrder" : "",
            "internalNotes" : "",
            "applicationUnits" : "Hours",
            "applicationLimit" : "0",
            "applicationCycle" : "CalendarMonth",
            "applicationUnlimitedFlag" : true,
            "oneTimeFlag" : false,
            "coverAgreementTime" : true,
            "coverAgreementProduct" : false,
            "coverAgreementExpense" : false,
            "expiredDays" : "0",
            "billCycleId" : "2",
            "billOneTimeFlag" : false,
            "billTermsId" : 12,
            "billAmount" : "0",
            "periodType" : null,
            "_id" : ObjectId("57c7bd9051666ac615bc8402"),
            "_info" : {
                "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2016-06-01T16:48:03.000Z"),
                "updatedBy" : "Ali            "
            },
            "workType" : {
                "id" : "3",
                "name" : "Remote",
                "_info" : null
            },
            "workRole" : {
                "id" : "5",
                "name" : "Support Engineer",
                "_info" : null
            },
            "contact" : {
                "id" : "810",
                "name" : "Jarrod Rogers"
            },
            "agreementType" : {
                "id" : "19",
                "name" : "Complete Managed Services"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "125",
            "name" : "Managed Services Agreement",
            "parentAgreementId" : null,
            "customerPO" : "",
            "locationId" : "11",
            "businessUnitId" : 2,
            "startDate" : "2016-06-01T04:00:00Z",
            "endDate" : null,
            "noEndingDateFlag" : true,
            "cancelledFlag" : false,
            "dateCancelled" : null,
            "reasonCancelled" : "",
            "slaId" : null,
            "workOrder" : "",
            "internalNotes" : "",
            "applicationUnits" : null,
            "applicationLimit" : "0",
            "applicationCycle" : null,
            "applicationUnlimitedFlag" : false,
            "oneTimeFlag" : false,
            "coverAgreementTime" : false,
            "coverAgreementProduct" : false,
            "coverAgreementExpense" : false,
            "expiredDays" : "0",
            "billCycleId" : "2",
            "billOneTimeFlag" : false,
            "billTermsId" : 12,
            "billAmount" : "0",
            "periodType" : null,
            "_id" : ObjectId("57c7bd9051666ac615bc8404"),
            "_info" : {
                "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2016-06-01T16:17:45.000Z"),
                "updatedBy" : "Ali            "
            },
            "contact" : {
                "id" : "810",
                "name" : "Jarrod Rogers"
            },
            "agreementType" : {
                "id" : "32",
                "name" : "Agreement Template"
            }
        }
    ],
    "companySite" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 1125,
            "name" : "Main",
            "addressLine1" : "5425 W. Spring Creek Pkwy #270",
            "addressLine2" : null,
            "city" : "Plano",
            "state" : "TX",
            "zip" : "75024",
            "faxNumber" : null,
            "taxCodeId" : null,
            "expenseReimbursement" : null,
            "primaryAddressFlag" : true,
            "defaultShippingFlag" : false,
            "defaultBillingFlag" : true,
            "defaultMailingFlag" : false,
            "_id" : ObjectId("57c7beb951666ac615bc84e5"),
            "country" : {
                "id" : 1,
                "name" : "United States",
                "_info" : null
            },
            "_info" : {
                "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2016-09-01T05:12:28.000Z"),
                "updatedBy" : "LabTechInt"
            }
        }
    ],
    "status" : {
        "id" : "1",
        "name" : "Active"
    },
    "country" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "United States",
        "_info" : null
    },
    "id" : "19390",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I want to count both the number of agreements and the number of contacts in a document, and group the data on company name and orgId.

This is my desired output:

```json
{
  "Company":        "Multi-Metal Manufacturing",
  "Organization":   "1",
  "AgreementCount" : 1,
  "ContactCount" :   4
}
```

I tried this solution, but result is not as expected; it gives me a general count of all fields, but I want a specific count:

```json
return Company.aggregate(
  {"$unwind":"$agreement"},
  {"$unwind":"$contact"},
  {"$unwind":"$companySite"},
  { $group: {
    _id: {
      "Organization": "$orgId",
      "Company": "$name"
    },
    "count": { $sum: 1 } } },
  {"$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "Company": "$_id.Company",
    "Organization":"$_id.Organization",
    "Count": "$count"
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming **Companyname/orgId** is unique, you can use `$size` which will get the size of your arrays to make this pretty simple:

```
[
    {
        $project:{
            _id:false,
            Company: "$name",
            Organization: "$orgId",
            AgreementCount: {
                $size: {$ifNull: ["$agreement",[]]}
            },
            ContactCount: {
                $size: {$ifNull: ["$contact",[]]}
            }
        }
    }
]
```

If **Companyname/orgId** are not unique, then you can introduce a `$group` stage to sum the counts produced by `$size`:

```
[
    {
        $project:{
            _id:false,
            Company: "$name",
            Organization: "$orgId",
            AgreementCount: {
                $size: {$ifNull: ["$agreement",[]]}
            },
            ContactCount: {
                $size: {$ifNull: ["$contact",[]]}
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id:{
                Company: "$Company",
                Organization: "$Organization"
            },
            AgreementCount: {$sum:"$AgreementCount"},
            ContactCount: {$sum:"$ContactCount"}
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            _id: false,
            Company: "$_id.Company",
            Organization: "$_id.Organization",
            AgreementCount: true,
            ContactCount: true
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Hello the query you pasted with unique does not work as expected, it give zero for all 
and the query you pasted for not unique, does not group by on company

Comment: I got this solution 

db.company.aggregate({$unwind:"$contact"},{$unwind:"$agreement"},{$group:{_id:{"company":"$name","organization":"$orgId"},"Contact":{$addToSet:"$contact._id"},"Agreement":{$addToSet:"$agreement._id"}}},
{"$project":{_id:0,"Company":"$_id.company","Organization":"$_id.organization","AgreementCount":{$size:"$Agreement"},"ContactCount":{$size:"$Contact"}}}).pretty();

Comment: This solution works with the dataset you provided in your question.  Are you perhaps, working with a dataset other than what you indicated?  For example, you reference the path "$contact._id", but there is no such path in your provided sample data.  A contact array element only contains the property, Name.  Example {"name": "Services"}.  Other than that, the primary issue with the accepted answer and the solution in your comment is that it's inefficient.  You are unnecessarily unwinding both arrays, creating essentially duplicate data, and then removing duplicates using $addToSet.

Comment: I just want to count the number of contacts and number of agreements in my whole company collection
Then I want to group by the count on company name and orgId.

I am new in mongo, If you think there is a better solution then please tell me. 

I am updating the sample document.

Comment: I apologize for the data set, actually its so large that is Why I did not post early

Comment: I updated my answer to match your new sample data.  The only change that I needed to make was to change $Companyname to $name.  I'm assuming that's the column you want to use for the company name now.

Comment: Your answer calculate agreements exactly right, But it is not calculating contacts


I am using this query 


{
        $project:{
            _id:false,
            Company: "$name",
            Organization: "$orgId",
            AgreementCount: {
                $size: { "$ifNull": [ "$agreement", [] ] }
            },
            ContactCount: {
                $size: { "$ifNull": [ "$contact", [] ] }
            }
        }
    }

Comment: view the output http://imgur.com/a/LOPUQ
It is working fine for agreementCount, but contact is zero

Comment: why we are using project two times in not unique case ?

Comment: The second $project is not necessary. It's just used to bring the $group _id key components (Company, Organization) back to the root level of the output document.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.company.aggregate(
  {$unwind:"$contact"},
  {$unwind:"$agreement"},
  {$group:
    {_id: {"company":"$name","organization":"$orgId"},
     "Contact":{$addToSet:"$contact._id"},
     "Agreement":{$addToSet:"$agreement._id"}
    }
  },
  {"$project":
    {_id:0,
     "Company":"$_id.company",
     "Organization":"$_id.organization",
     "AgreementCount":{$size:"$Agreement"},
     "ContactCount":{$size:"$Contact"}
    }
  }).pretty();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return Company.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        ITBCompanyId: 1,
        name: 1,
        contact: {
            $size: "$contact"
        },
        agreement: {
            $size: "$agreement"
        },
        whoIs: {
            $size: "$whois"
        },
        companySite: {
            $size: "$companySite"
        }
    }
}])
```